# Why is "\" invalid in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

While writing `"\"` in Chrome console I get the following error:

```
VM242674:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

In Firefox it gives following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

while writting `"\\"` gives:
`"\\"` in both browsers

What is the proper way to write `"\"` in JavaScript?

Comment: You can (and generally should) use single quotes to delimit a string that contains double quotes - `'""'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not let the rendering of a string in the console, which may display strings including escape sequences and wrapped in quotes because it is a *debugging tool*, confuse you.

If you want a slash in a string, then escape it with a second slash.

```js
const string = "\\";
const node = document.createTextNode(string);
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Comment: Is it a bug or it is meant to be like this?

Comment: @YadavDhakal — It's meant to be like that.

Comment: @YadavDhakal a backslash is supposed to be part of an escape sequence, e.g `"\n"` is a new line. So, `"\"` is the *opening double quote* of a string, followed by the escape sequence `\"` (which just means a `"` character in the string) but *no closing double quote*. This is interpretation tends to hold across many programming languages - Java, C#, PHP, just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

`"\\"` is the correct way to write \

Example: `console.log('This will print as a single back slash \\')`